# Formatting a Date (Sharepoint Designer)

Tags: sharepoint, xpath

I am trying to format the dates correctly in Sharepoint Designer.

This line of code does work but I am getting spurious results as my dates are in UK formatting.

```
<xsl:value-of
      select=
"number(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(
            ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(FormatDate(@DateSent,2057,1)))))-
 number(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(
            ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(FormatDate(ddwrt:Today(),2057,1)))))"
/>
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
FormatDate is not a valid XSLT or XPath function.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function `FormatDate(...)` in the XPath standard. Sharepoint Designer has one which is in the `ddwrt:` namespace you used for some other functions. For calling this, add the namespace.

```
number(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@DateSent,2057,1))))))
-
number(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(ddwrt:FormatDate(ddwrt:Today(),2057,1)))))"
```

Comment: Awesome!  Totally worked with the addition of string() around @DateSent.  Thanks for your help with this!